# How to manage with data from fetch promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I am beginner in JS and React.

I have a problem:

```js
import React from "react";

import JsonApi from "../../services/jsonApi";

const UserPage = () => {
  const jsonApi = new JsonApi(); //it is my class which has methods 
                                 //to manage with data(get,post,etc);

  const user = jsonApi.getUser(); //returns promise,but i need an object with data!
                                  //promise has such view:
                                  //[[Prototype]]: Promise
                                  //[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
                                  //[[PromiseResult]]: Object  !!!!i need this data!!!!
  console.log(user); //Promise.

  /* i know that a i can do so:
     user.then((data) => console.log(data));

     but,using this way,i can only log!But i need an object with data!
  */


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>{user.name}</h1> 
      <p>Here are info about users!</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserPage;
```

I understand that i need to use `await` before `const user = jsonApi.getUser();`

but we can do that only inside `async` functions.

So,i tried to do that: `const UserPage = async () => { }`

but i had a mistake:

[image]

Comment: A React component cannot be an `async` function, because a promise of an element isn't itself a valid element. You also probably don't want to make a request every time the component renders - look into `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform side effects in react you should consider using [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. After the effect you need to store the data retrieved in react state by using the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook. In the end your code would look like below:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import JsonApi from "../../services/jsonApi";

const UserPage = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const jsonApi = new JsonApi();
    jsonApi.getUser().then((user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!user) return null;
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      <p>Here are info about users!</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserPage;
```

Keep in mind that the user is not populated until you async `getUser` resolves, so you have to handle the case where `user` data are not yet present, either by rendering nothing (null) or by showing some loading state in between.